# Masking a specified column in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Here is my grid initialization:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UT.CRM.ViewModels.DemoUserListViewModel> ()
    .Name("demoUsers")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerName).Title("Ad Soyad").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.Login).Title("Hesap").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.DayCount).Title("Toplam Gün").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.TradeCount).Title("Toplam İşlem").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.RegistrationDate).Title("Kayıt").Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("eq")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Title("E-Posta").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
        columns.Bound(c => c.Phone).Title("Phone").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 690px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetDemoUsersReport", "Reports"))
    )
)
```

As you see I have a column having phone values. I want these phone values to be formatted as below:

05356645879 -> ****664****

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a `ClientTemplate` as below:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Phone).ClientTemplate(@"#: phone.replace(/^\\d{4}|\\d{4}$/g, \'****\') #").Title...
```

I could not test it with ASP.Net, but [here is a demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uqInA) in pure javascript. Any problems please let me know.

UPDATE: I forgot to say that the best and safer way to achieve that is to do the same thing, but in your server side. So the user cannot get the information in the raw request result. But if you think that isn't necessary, it is ok.